# how to validate 2 fields with Minimum/Maximum compare validation in ionic3?

Tags: sass, ionic3, angular6

Working on reactive form group which contain 2 fields such as min and max, data is coming form hard-coded array data . when we enter the value on respective field just want to show validation that min value should be greater than max

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

create a form as bellow

```
createForm() {
    this.personalDataForm = new FormGroup({
      fieldOne: new FormControl("", [Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(15)])
// ...
    });
  }
```

add validations to your template

```
<form [formGroup]="personalDataForm">
  <ion-row>
   <label class="lbl-lnu">fieldOne :</label>
   <input type="text" class="input-lnu" formControlName="fieldOne">
   <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="personalDataForm.controls.fieldOne.errors && (personalDataForm.controls.fieldOne.dirty || personalDataForm.controls.fieldOne.touched)">
      <p class="error-msg" *ngIf="personalDataForm.controls.fieldOne.errors.minlength">Minimum length is 5</p>
      <p class="error-msg" *ngIf="personalDataForm.controls.fieldOne.errors.maxlength">Maximun length is 15</p>
   </div>
   </div>
 </ion-row>
</form>
```

to fire validation when submit, use bellow function

```
function isValid(): boolean {
  const valid = this.personalDataForm.valid
  if (!valid) { // if not valid fire validation
    Object.keys(this.personalDataForm.controls).forEach(field => {
        const control = this.personalDataForm.get(field);
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
      });
  }
  return valid; // if form data valid return true, otherwise false
}
```